# Can I set the front camera as default camera?

Tags: camera

Is there any way to set the front facing camera as the default one? Doesn't matter what lens it is. Doesn't have to be the Nokia Camera.

I love taking selfies...

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you cannot set the default camera in windows phone currently. You can definitely put your suggestion [here](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Nokia Glam me](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/nokia-glam-me/40b6a721-15d2-4843-a746-774bd7b9bda9) lens.

Comment: I'm unable to set the app as my default camera app